# What do ++ and +- mean in a Debian diff file?

Tags: git, diff, debian

I'm currently viewing the [Ubuntu Rhythmbox source diff](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/rhythmbox/rhythmbox_0.12.8-0ubuntu3.diff.gz), (you can view this via `gzip -d < rhythmbox_0.12.8-0ubuntu6.diff.gz | less` on the command line). Here's an excerpt:

```
+diff --git a/plugins/status-icon/status-icon-ui.xml b/plugins/status-icon/statu
s-icon-ui.xml
+index a5cb6e1..a4eee9d 100644
+--- a/plugins/status-icon/status-icon-ui.xml
++++ b/plugins/status-icon/status-icon-ui.xml
+@@ -15,12 +15,26 @@
+       <menuitem name="PreviousTray" action="ControlPrevious"/>
+       <menuitem name="NextTray" action="ControlNext"/>
+       <separator/>
+-      <menuitem name="ShowWindowTray" action="TrayShowWindow"/>
++      <menuitem name="ShowWindowTray" action="TrayToggleWindow"/>
```

There are several lines containing unfamiliar `++` and `+-` prefixes which I'm not familiar with. I suspect it has something to do with the git format, but can't find an explanation after some googling.

What does it mean? Is this specific to Debian diffs or git? Where can I find the definitive explanation for this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `+` means that it's a line added in the top diff. The `+` or `-` that follows is the first character in the line of the patch contained within the diff. So, you're looking at a diff within a diff.

Comment: thanks, as soon as i read this i felt very stupid. i was in a rush at the time and didn't notice that teh entire file had + in the first column